# Webpage horizontal scrollbar and not whole page visible

Tags: css, scrollbar, horizontal-scrolling

I have a problem when viewing my page on lower resolution monitors. Not the whole page is visible. There is a part on the left that is out of window and cannot be scrolled to.

Way to test it is by opening a webpage http://www.good3dprojector.com 
and shrinking the window size. Now you can see that the left side of my page is not visible.

Thank you for your help :-)

**EDIT:**
I want to accomplish this:

[image]

I want header logo, menu, and the body to be on one straight line as it is in the picture. (but it breaks up if the window size gets too small, because I'm using negative margin left)

Answer (score 0):

Your social media bar has a fixed position with the `right` attribute. You should use left if you want it to stay on your left side.
Your navigation and logo have a negative margin left. This leads to the problem, that your elements are moving out of the window when they actually reach the zero pixel mark on the left side of the browser.

Comment: Thank you, how can I overcome using negative margin left? Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to accomplish. On the one hand you are using the `margin: 0 auto;` methods to center your header, but on the other hand you are positioning it with `left: -45px`. Do you want to centered or in a specific position?

Comment: I edited the original post for you, look there. And big THANKS for your help and patience :-)

Comment: Still not sure how you want your navi to behave. But try putting your header into your content div. Then removing the `position: absolute` from your #globalNavi and the `left: -45px` from .headerbox.
You just need to change your body's background. It doesn't line up everything on the left, but this isn't possible with your current markup. Try to clean your markup a bit fron unnessary stuff.

Comment: Thank you, I will maybe change the wordpress theme to something more user friendly. Now I'm gonna play with the parameters, thank you :-)